# Does $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}e^{-nx}\cos{nx}$ converge point-wise $\forall \space x \in [1, \infty)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

Does the infinite series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}e^{-nx}\cos{nx}$ converge point-wise for all $x \in [1, \infty)$?

Facts that help: $$|\cos{nx}| \leq 1 \\ x \geq 1 \quad \forall \space te^{t} > 0 \\ e^{-nx} \leq e^{-n} \quad \forall \space x \geq 1$$

We need to find a series that is less than or equal to the series above. and that i can't do :(

I think the series we searching is 1/n^2 and the sum of it is 2. Is it right?
edit: damn its from n=0 not from n=1 so I have no idea what to do :(

Comment: In the future, please use mathjax when typing your questions so it is easily readable for everyone. Also, what have you done so far?

Comment: I found all the facts that should help to solve this. all I need is series we know the sum of and <= this series

Comment: Have you tried applying them? If so, post your work so far

Comment: I tried over and over for an hour and I think that 1/n^2 is the answer and the sum of it is 2. Am I right?

Comment: What about the geometric series $e^{-nx}$?

Comment: it's clearly >=e−nxcosnx (can someone teach me how to write it this mathmatical way) but what's the sum of it? how do you caculate it?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence

Comment: Bach so what's the sum of this series e^−nx?

Comment: Are you sure you want "a series that is **less** than or equal to the series above"?

Comment: e^−nx is more or equal to the series above, no less

Answer (score 1):

I think I have some ideas that could help you out.

Check out this link 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test

With the Weierstrass test you prove something stronger than point-wise and that is the uniform convergence.

In a few words, if something converges in an interval uniformly then it must have converged pointwise.
So... here I want to use the Weierstrass test in order to do that I must 
$$|e^{-nx}cos(nx)| \leq |e^{-nx}|\leq |e^{-n}|=e^{-n}=M_{n}$$
So all we need is prove that the following series converges
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty M_n$$
In order to prove that I used the Ratio Test
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}|\frac{M_{n+1}}{M_n}|=\lim_{x\to \infty}|\frac{e^{-(n+1)}}{e^{-n}}|=e^{-1}<1$$
So, as the series with Mn converges, we can use the Weierstrass test to say that:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-nx}cos(nx)$$
converges absolutely and uniformly on x $\epsilon$ [1,$\infty$).

And as it converges uniformly on [1,$\infty$) in particular it converges point-wise on [1,$\infty$).
I know that it starts with n=0 but as it converges uniformly with n=1 then it also converges uniformly with n=0, it's just adding 1 to the series.

I hope this helps

Comment: yes that helped a lot, but what's the sum of 1/e^n ? is that e/(e-1)?

Comment: yup, that's correct as (1/e) < 1, the sum from 0 to infinity of 1/e^n  = 1/(1-(1/e)) = e/(e-1)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series